# Unable to access "90d" tab on "question-close-stats" page

Tags: bug

When I try to go to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) I get this error:

[image]

Comment: For me it just times out.  I don't get the cloudflare page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up again: https://askubuntu.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days.

Comment: Probably a system glitch. Definitely working now.